# An Error in UseState() function - Expected ;

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-hooks

```
const [value, setValue] = useState();
```

expected ';' in place of '='

I am using this npm to get Mobile Number from User with Country Code.

npm i react-phone-number-input

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input/v/3.0.13

This is the example used by them.

```js
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'

const [value, setValue] = useState()

return (
  <PhoneInput
    placeholder="Enter phone number"
    value={value}
    onChange={setValue}
  />
)
```

Please help me out. Also suggest me another possible solution to get Phone Number form User with Country Code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use a `React.js Hook` inside a functional component. So, you need to create a functional component like this:

```
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input';
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css';

const MyPhoneComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()

  return (
    <PhoneInput
      placeholder="Enter phone number"
      value={value}
      onChange={setValue}
    />
  )
}

export default MyPhoneComponent;
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I am using class in this problem. When i declare

`const [value, setValue] = useState()`

Below `render()` I get a Invalid Hook call Error

Comment: Unfortunately, hooks are not accessible in class component.

Comment: I tried the exact same code without class. I'm getting the error Text String Must me rendered inside the <Text> Component

Comment: Can you please share a code sample so i can have a look?

Comment: import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input';

const LoginForm = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()

  return (
    <PhoneInput 
      value={value}
      onChange={setValue}
    />
  )
}

export default LoginForm;

Comment: Can always use alternatives to hook for class components.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'

const MyPhone = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState();

return (
  <PhoneInput
    placeholder="Enter phone number"
    value={value}
    onChange={setValue}
  />
)
}
```